# Webpack to include files loaded by variables

Tags: node.js, webpack, aws-lambda

I'm creating a lambda function that will include modules based on properties that get passed into it.  Something like:

```
export handler (event, ctx, cb) => {
  fn = require("./" + event.module);
  fn(cb);
}
```

where `event.module` is something like `categories`.

In order to do this, I'm using webpack to build the project. However, Webpack will not load `./categories` since it can't know about it.

For the time being I'm just including:

```
const categores = require("./categories");
const routes = {categories};
// ...
fn = routes[event.module];
```

However this also doesn't work because the lambda function complains: `"Cannot find module './categories'"`

My webpack is working, and the config is:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: "./index.js", target: "node",
    output: { path: "./lib", filename: "index.js" },
    module: {
        noParse: [/node_modules/],
        loaders: [{
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: "babel",
                exclude: [/node_modules/]}, ] } };
```

Is there any way for me to get webpack to load all of the module files I need (I don't mind specifying them individually). If so, can I get lambda to load them?

What would work best would be if I could simply copy the module files into the output directory after running them through the loaders.